# How can I solve the inequation $(x-4)(x+2) \leq 0$?

Tags: inequality

I've been stuck on this textbook question.

So with the inequality given we can assume that $x \leq -2$ or $x \leq 4$, right?

I've gotten confused on the final step, not sure how it all combines into one.

Comment: Sketch the function $y=(x-4)(x+2)$ and see the interval of $x$ values for which produce a $y$ value less than or equal to $0$.

Comment: Check the sign of each factor on the intervals $\,x \lt -2\,$, $\,-2 \lt x \lt 4\,$, and $\,x \gt 4\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I'm not sure how you went from x < -2 to -2 < x

Comment: @videogamelover You know the expression is $\,0\,$ when $\,x \in \{-2,4\}\,$, which leaves the $\,3\,$ intervals $\,(-\infty, -2)\,$, $\,(-2, 4)\,$ and $\,(4, \infty)\,\,$ to check. The three cases can also be written as $\,x \lt -2\,$, $\,-2 \lt x \lt 4\,$ and $\,x \gt 4\,$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach it differently from studying each case separately:
\begin{align*}
(x - 4)(x + 2) \leq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (x - 4)(x - 4 + 6) \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - 4)^{2} + 6(x - 4) \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - 4)^{2} + 6(x - 4) + 9 \leq 9\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ((x - 4) + 3)^{2} \leq 9\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - 1)^{2} \leq 9\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x - 1| \leq 3\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -2 \leq x \leq 4
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !